# Capturing preceding whitespace in Julia

Tags: regex, string, julia, whitespace

I have a very long piece of code that I need to add to, and would prefer to do it using a script rather than write myself for fear of introducing errors.

I have commands that look like this

```
    rename oldname newname 

      rename oldname2 newname2
```

I want to, whenever I see the command "rename" I want to add a "note" command

```
    rename oldname newname 
        note newname: "A Note"

        rename oldname2 newname2
            note newname2: "A Note"
```

I am using Julia's read and write features to do this, and it has been very easy so far.

```
f = open("renaming.txt") # open input file
g = open("renaming_output.txt", "w") # open output file

for ln in eachline(f)
   write(g, "$ln \n") # write the command, no matter what it is
   stripped = lstrip("$ln") # Strip whitespace so I can use "startswith" command
   if startswith(stripped, "ren")
          words = split("$ln", " ") # split on space to get the "newvar" name
          println("$ln \n") #check that I am working with a rename command
              println("note ", words[3]":") # check that the note function prints
              note_command = string("note ", words[3], ": \n") # construct the note command
              write(g, note_command) #write it to the output file. 
       end
end
```

My issue is with the indentation. The above code writes the "note" command on the far left, without any indentation. However, Ideally I would like the note command to be indented one level further than the rename command. But I can't figure out how to capture all the preceeding whitespace.

I presume that the answer involves using the `match` and `m.match` functions, but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Julia 0.7 the simplest change in your code would be to replace

```
println("note ", words[3]":")
```

with

```
println(first(ls, search(ls, 'r')-1), "    note ", words[3]":")
```

Using regular expressions you can write `rx = r"(?:(?!r).)*"` at the start of your code and then:

```
println(match(rx, ls).match, "    note ", words[3]":")
```

In both cases we take care to retain the start of `ls` till `'r'` in its original form.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I am using 6.1, and search() does not return an array, simply the first appearance of the character. Perhaps it does in .7? I have been meaning to update.

Answer (score 1):

With Julia 6.1, my solution, with the help the answer, is as follows

```
if startswith(stripped, "ren") & !startswith(stripped, "renvars")
          leftpad = "   " ^ search("$ln", 'r')
          words = split(stripped, " ")
          varname = string(leftpad, " note ", words[3], ": ", words[2], " \n")
          print(varname)
          write(g, varname)
   end
```

With the `leftpad = ^ search("$ln", 'r')` being the key addition. Given that the left padding of my code is always tabs, I just insert the number of tabs as there are characters before the first `r`. This solution works in 0.6.1, but search may behave differently in .7.

Comment: My solution is handling correctly all whitespace removed by `lstrip`, i.e. ' ', \t, \n, \v, \f, and \r. Of course your is OK if you know you have only tabs before "ren".